# Faster to Falco AC Bair or SHFFL Bair?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Which occurs in fewer frames: as Falco, auto-cancelled (AC) backwards aerial attack (Bair) or short-hop fast-fall L-cancelled (SHFFLed) backwards aerial attack?

I'm wondering which is safer (at least on shield hit). Traditionally, SHFFLing is recommended. AC Bair may have less landing lag, but probably has more air-time. Vice versa for SHFFL bair.

Comment: As you said, generally SHFFL is recommended, but it also depends on what you define as safe. There are more factors than just how good or bad it's on the shield in frames; most notably, your control over spacing matters a lot. Unless you are almost at professional level, as Falco has a fairly good range I'd recommend SHFFL as it is sufficient for most of your bair-use needs. Air time is the important point, as safety on shield is no good if the opponent has a chance to hit you inbetween.